# UI Button image replaces the title. But I want BOTH the text and image and title to show

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to have a "Sign in using Facebook" button where the button has the facebook icon to the left of the text. But when I use signInFacebookButton.setImage....., the text disappears and only the logo appears directly centred in the button. It looks like the image has overridden the text. Can someone help me solve this issue so that my button can display BOTH the icon and the text on my button, like in this picture
[image: Button looks Like This]

I have already tried using a background image instead. But the background image fills the entire button and has the text overlying it.

```
signInFacebookButton.setTitle("Sign in with Facebook", for: .normal)
signInFacebookButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
signInFacebookButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 58/255, green: 85/255, blue: 159/255, alpha: 1)

signInFacebookButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
signInFacebookButton.clipsToBounds = true
signInFacebookButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "facebook"), for: .normal)
signInFacebookButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

**UPDATE:** 
Now my button looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKRW9.png). I am having trouble getting the text to be directly next to the icon.

Comment: You just need a bigger button. Both text and image will show if there is room.

Comment: I am just getting an identical looking bigger button. I still have the issue.

Comment: i think facebook is using text and logo on an image, You should create an image with text and your required logo and use that image on button

Comment: Well I assure you that buttons with both image and title are quite common.

Comment: @matt you are right event i have used them most of times, in her case i think button she needs an image with  logo and title over it and then using that image on button. what you say?

Comment: I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTAaJbVoMgQ&t=1s.  at 1:38, notice that both the image and text appear using the same code. I am not sure where my error is.

Comment: did you tried this? signInFacebookButton.imageView?.contentMode = .left

Comment: its image of fb SDK i think they are using it as image what iam saying you is download same image and place it in your assets and using it with just 
signInFacebookButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "facebook"), for: .normal)
will solve your problem

Comment: I understand what you are saying Abu UI Hassan. But for some reason in the tutorial I am following the person adds both a text element and an image element to the button.

Comment: Alexandr Kolesnik, this also did not work unfortunately

Comment: have you set your button type to custom?

Comment: Also check background color and title color are not of same color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find solution to your problem by doing following

1. Check background color and title color are not of same color
2. Change State Config to default
3. Setting insets from showed in image set your values according to your need[image: See unage].
4. check your facebook image is not larger then required try by reducing image size.

Comment: #4 is the answer!!! You are amazing thank you for your help. I tried a different facebook icon and sure enough it works.

Comment: Although now I am getting a big space between the facebook logo and my title. How can I make them directly next to each other with no space?

Comment: you need to set some attirbutes for custom button.

Comment: you may use image insets from left Or you may use title insets from right Even you can use Both inset image insets and title insets to keep content in middle .

Comment: If answer #4 Solved the problem you should accept answer as it will help others to find right solution for thier problem :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
signInFacebookButton.setTitle("Sign in with Facebook", for: .normal)
signInFacebookButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
signInFacebookButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 58/255, green: 85/255, blue: 159/255, alpha: 1)

signInFacebookButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
signInFacebookButton.clipsToBounds = true
let facebookImage = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .facebookSquare, style: .brands, textColor: .white, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
signInFacebookButton.setImage(facebookImage, for: .normal)
signInFacebookButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

I am using [fontAwesome](https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift) pod for facebook image